# To stop form submit on every refresh after one submit in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, post, insert, duplicates

After form submission , any number of refresh is storing the data that many times in the db.
ie. `!empty($_POST)` is always true after on submission.

How can I stop the submission without redirecting the page/url. As I want to stay in the same page.

I am using form_open() and form_submit() i codeigniter.

### in view

```
    <?php echo form_open("",array('method' => 'POST'));?>
  /* form fields */
```

'Send', 'value' => 'Send Notifications',"name"=>"send_notification")); ?>

---

### in controller

```
`if (!empty($_POST['send_notification'])) {
      /* validation rules  & data*/
      if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
         $this->model->insert($data);
      }
 }`
```

How can I stop the duplicate record insertion, I have tried , `unset($_POST)` , isset() , if($this->input->post()) , nothing seems to work.

Comment: you can redirect page to same controller using `redirect('controller/function');` and if you want to show message than you can redirect with something attached to it, like `redirect('controller/function/?success');`. and then in controller `if(isset($_GET['success'])){ $data['success'] ="Your success message here"; }`

Comment: thanks, flash message before redirecting to the same controller helped.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a `redirect();` to the same age after the insert function.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. It may help someone

**Controller file :**

```
public function success()
{
    $_SESSION['txnid'] = $this->input->post('txnid');
    $this->bind->set_order();
    $this->load->view('success');
}
```

**Model file :**

```
public function set_order()
{
    $txnid = $_SESSION['txnid'];
    $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT * from orders where transaction_id = '$txnid'");
    $result = $qry->result_array();
    if($qry->num_rows() == 0 )
    {
     //add to database here
    }

    else
    {
      // do nothing
    }
}
```

I am adding txnid to database on submit. So if it tries to resubmit, it  checks if txnid already exist or not.